# How to reduce Magento Product Prices reindexing time for 1M product with 5K customer group?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, reindex, mysql-indexes

I'm working with magento 1.9.2 website for a manufacture company which has over `1M product (each product have 5+ customer grouping price and trier pricing)` and `5k+ customer group`.

I did all the basic performance measures.

Buyed a dedicated server, now website performs good except the indexes.
while reindexing `'Product Prices'` takes one or more days (some times it never stopped) and pricing is not being updated properly in frontend (note: prices updated regularly through api).

So i planned to store the pricing data's to my custom table and i reflected this to frontend.
Even all the products stored all the prices (0.00) in related tables (Magento tables).

This also takes too much time to re-indexing all.

***What I tried Previously?***

Truncated the price related tables.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
```

if i truncated the above table, then the product collection not showing in frontend.

***Now what i want to know?***

1. when truncated the above tables why the products not showing?
2. how to avoid this issues?
3. where i go to remove the join query to remove the pricing related collections?

I am looking for permananet solutions for avoiding to store prices, customer prices and trier prices in magento db.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing we typically do is have 2 servers, 1 for website/files and 1 for the database itself.

It would be worth doing a repair and optimize on the tables within the database with something like

```
mysqlcheck -u -p --auto-repair
```

Also i'd recommend giving mysql tuner a try, it will check over your database setup and then give you recommendations on things to improve for performance and stability: https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl

Answer (score 1):

Please review the refman for TRUNCATE purpose.  You will find you REMOVED all rows from each table listed.  Probably a pretty bad consequence resulted.  Whoever advised you to do this should be avoided in the future ( they will only get you into more TROUBLE).

For tuning assistance, please review my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch with me by Skype.

Comment: @sathish When you are ready to improve performance of your MySQL instance, let me know.